# OkHttp + ALPN + APNS - result is SSL handshake_failure

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications, http2, okhttp, alpn

Trying to use OkHttp (v3.4.1) to send requests via HTTP/2 to Apple's Production APNS servers (api.push.apple.com:443).

I followed the steps here to enable ALPN:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html

My environment is:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
```

And so I am using:

```
alpn-boot-7.1.0.v20141016.jar
```

I believe I have confirmed that ALPN is working since, whenever I attempt to send a push, I am seeing something similar to the following in the logs (note: ALPN.debug = true):

```
[C] ALPN protocols [h2, spdy/3.1, http/1.1] for 62587aa8[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=api.push.apple.com/17.172.233.39,port=443,localport=55984]]
[C] ALPN protocols [h2, spdy/3.1, http/1.1] for 74adce4e[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=api.push.apple.com/17.172.233.39,port=443,localport=55990]]
[C] ALPN protocols [h2, spdy/3.1, http/1.1] for 221ebc09[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=api.push.apple.com/17.172.234.15,port=443,localport=55993]]
[C] ALPN protocols [h2, spdy/3.1, http/1.1] for fcb045f[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=api.push.apple.com/17.172.234.15,port=443,localport=55998]]
[C] ALPN protocols [h2, spdy/3.1, http/1.1] for 3fd11dec[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=api.push.apple.com/17.172.234.22,port=443,localport=56004]]
```

I also see the following error after the above (note: SSL debug enabled):

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

I have confirmed that my universal SSL Certificate for APNS is valid as our legacy code, non-HTTP/2 code (based on Java-apns) can use it and send push notifications without issue.

From scanning the full SSL debug log, I get the impression that the core issue here is that the communication between my client and the APNS servers never transitions to HTTP/2. It is, however, unclear to me what other steps I need to take in order to insure this transition takes place.

I have sent a developer support request to Apple for feedback, but I figured I would post here as well in case anyone had more insight.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like HTTP/2 isn't supported by ALPN?

Comment: Does your legacy code use OkHTTP for SSL?

Comment: OkHttp definitely supports HTTP/2 with ALPN

Comment: without the full ssl debug log its hard to guess why.  How are you setting client authentication e.g. providing your client cert?

Comment: @YuriSchimke, can you clarify what you mean by "providing client cert"? Do you want sample code or are you looking for file format, etc? 
Also, I have a debug log from `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` that I can provide, but it's rather long and has some sensitive info in it. Is there a particular section that you are interested in seeing?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html the client needs to authenticate. This isn't usual for most usage of SSL

Comment: @chris.o. - Can you pls let me know how you solved the issue? Am facing a similar issue.

Comment: @csharpnewbie I never actually solved the issue with the aforementioned stack. I ended up using Pushy instead (https://github.com/relayrides/pushy) and it worked out quite well. Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: @chris.o. - Thanks for the update.